# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NativeScript encountered a fatal error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: NativeClass

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, nativescript

```
While running the app on simulator or real iOS device, it gives below error.
Any help would be appreciated.
```

[image: Crash error]

Git hub link - https://github.com/AjiteshMDK/GeoLocation-Update/issues/1

Answer (score 0):

What that's telling you is that you have code, whether your own or a plugin, that has not been updated for NativeScript 7/8.  See [this link](https://docs.nativescript.org/best-practices/native-class.html).

If the code is within a plugin, then may have to see if a revised version exists, or contact the plugin owner.  I've had two cases recently where I had to migrate a plugin myself.